# a2billing step rate not taking the right time?

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to use stepping rate in a2billing , by defining a rate-plan where in a special day , the price differs from the rest of the week , when I choose the time from the week [start-time] there is a gap between the real time and the specified time in the setup while doing the actual test , in simulator everything is good

my question is what parameters are related to the time for the rate to work as the setup

Regards,

Comment: As one of contributors can say, that your question have no way to be answer. Need hire someone who can debug php and just debug it.

Comment: @arheops , I can do debug , but so many cases to cover , and for the files , I reached A2Billing.RateEngineClass , and I will try to go further , thanks

Comment: sorry, this qestion is debug. debug is offtopic on SO

Comment: @arheops , thank but the question was if there is any parameters in the global variables , that I could check before going to debug code,
Regards